# How to get the value of a specific nested XML node in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I need to get the value of every "custom_field" named "ZIP" out of the following XML-file using PHP.
When I parse it, I always get either the values of all projects or an empty array?
Can somebody help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects total_count="237" offset="0" limit="100" type="array">
<project>
    <id>239</id>
    <name>ABC</name>
    <identifier></identifier>
    <description></description>
    <status>1</status>
    <is_public>false</is_public>
    <custom_fields type="array">
        <custom_field id="18" name="Name affix">
            <value></value>
        </custom_field>
        <custom_field id="20" name="ZIP">
            <value>X1111</value>
        </custom_field>
    </custom_fields>
    <created_on>2017-06-05T16:33:13Z</created_on>
    <updated_on>2017-06-19T13:46:08Z</updated_on>
</project>
<project>
    <id>240</id>
    <name>DEF</name>
    <identifier></identifier>
    <description></description>
    <status>1</status>
    <is_public>false</is_public>
    <custom_fields type="array">
        <custom_field id="18" name="Name affix">
            <value></value>
        </custom_field>
        <custom_field id="20" name="ZIP">
            <value>Y2222</value>
        </custom_field>
    </custom_fields>
    <created_on>2017-06-05T16:33:14Z</created_on>
    <updated_on>2017-06-05T16:33:14Z</updated_on>
</project>
...
```

I tried the following and get empty arrays:

```
$projects = simplexml_load_file($rm_host."/projects.xml?key=".$rm_sa_key."&limit=100");

foreach($projects->project as $project){

    $zip = $project->xpath('//custom_field[@name="ZIP"]');

    print_r($zip);
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

When I try to replace the string with the following, it returns the value of all items, not of the specific one:

```
zip = $project->xpath('//custom_fields[@type="array"]/custom_field[@name="ZIP"]')
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Similarities to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887910/get-the-values-of-the-child-nodes-with-php-dom

Comment: Is `//custom_field[@Name="ZIP"]` not working?

Comment: Seems to be working just fine over here ~ https://eval.in/859806. I suggest you look closely at what `$rm_host."/projects.xml?key=".$rm_sa_key."&limit=100"` is returning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked after trying and trying.

The correct string to get the specific value was:

```
$zip = $project->custom_fields->xpath('custom_field[@name="ZIP"]/value')[0];
```

Without the slash in front of the xpath.

Comment: There are various ways of testing your XPath, online testers like http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath, or I use Eclipse and I can check out what an expression is going to return interactively.  `//custom_fields/custom_field[@name="ZIP"]/value` should do a similar job just using XPath as you achieve here.